# Routes not found after deploy laravel app on shared server

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, server, shared

I'm trying to deploy a laravel application, but I'm keep getting this error: 
[My views are not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCV2x.png)

I used cPanel for deployment. I tried every solution I could find on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this is not a missing route error, just the view file was not found.

Checks that you have uploaded all the project files correctly, and that the view name is correct, these are the possible causes of the error.